# Unit testing: Prevent creation of duplicate objects

Tags: java, unit-testing

My professor gave us this homework exercise and has created a project with
a bunch of unit tests.
Our goal is to make sure we can pass those unit tests.
We have three classes.
A class called Person with a name and an age,
a class Speaker that extends Person,
and a class Attendee that also extends Person.
I am struggling with making sure that there are no duplicate people. `generateRandomString()` was implemented by the professor and just returns a random string.

I already created the class,
it's constructor,
getters,
and setters.
I also overrode the method `equals()` in the class `Person`

This is the test our professor gave us:

```java
    @Test
    public void testNoDuplicatePerson() {
      HashSet<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
      String name = generateRandomString();
      Person p = new Speaker(name);
      people.add(p);
      assertEquals(1,people.size());
      p = new Attendee(name);
      people.add(p);
      assertEquals(1,people.size());
    }
```

How can I pass this test?

EDIT: I decided to post the code of the three classes:

````
Person
 ```java
public abstract class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = 0;
    }

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Person))
            return false;
        Person converted = (Person) o;
        if (this.getName().equals(converted.getName()) && this.getAge() == converted.getAge())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
````

Speaker:

```java
public class Speaker extends Person {

    private int fee;

    public Speaker(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.fee = 0;
    }

    public Speaker(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
        this.fee = 0;
    }

    public Speaker(String name, int age, int fee) {
        super(name, age);
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    public int getFee() {
        return fee;
    }

    public void setFee(int fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Speaker " + this.getName() + " as a fee value of " + this.getFee() + ".";
    }
}
```

Attendee:

```java
public class Attendee extends Person {
    private boolean paid;

    public Attendee(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.paid=false;
    }

    public Attendee(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
        this.paid=false;
    }

    public boolean hasPaid(){
        if (this.paid==true)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Attendee "+this.getName()+(this.hasPaid() ? " has":" hasn't")+" paid its registration.";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the javadoc of HashSet say? When does the set consider that an object is a duplicate of another object? What do you conclude? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-

Comment: You are not supposed to change the unit test itself, only your code. From what I have understood is that I shouldn't be able to create a ```Person``` object if I already have a ```Person``` object that has a certain name. The line of code ```Person p=new Speaker(name); ``` should not work as I already have a person with the name. My question is how to solve this

Comment: No. You're free to have as many persons with the same name as you want. That's not what the test is testing. What the test is testing is that, if you try to add a person to a HashSet with the same name as another person already in the HashSet, then the HashSet should consider them as duplicates (since the size of the set stays at 1 after the addition). Hence my question: when does the set consider that an object is a duplicate of another object?

Comment: From the java documentation: " ```public boolean add(E e) ```
Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false."
I obviously have to override the equals method.

Comment: You got it right.

Comment: In that case my implementation of the equals method is wrong. Im editing my original post. Can you check what I have done wrong?

Comment: The test expects two persons with the same name to be equal. Your equals method only considers that two persons are equal when they have the same name **and the same age**. It could also be that your constructors are incorrect, or that you overrode equals in Speaker and/or Attendee.

Comment: In my constructor if no age is specified the age is set to zero so I believe that is not an issue. I didn't override equals in Speaker or Attendee either

Comment: Then something else is incorrect. Maybe Speaker and/or Attendee don't extend Person. Without the code, we can only make guesses. Use your debugger. Add a breakpoint to the equals method, and execute the test with the debugger. Find out why your method returns false instead of true.

Comment: In that case I will post those three classes. @JBNizet

Comment: You haven't overridden hashCode(). That's where the problem is. Look at the javadoc of hashCode() to understand what it's for and what the constraints are. Hash-based collections such as HashSet and HashMap need hashCode to be correctly implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @JB Nizet, when you override the `equals` method of a class,
you must override the `hashCode` method.
Note the name of the class in the jUnit test: **Hash**Set.
That depends on the `hashCode` method.
Solution:
a. Learn to read the java API docs.
Here is a link to the [v8 JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).
Read the `HashSet` page.
b. Implement the `hashCode` method.
You clearly have Internet access,
so, if you don't know how to implement a `hashCode` method,
try a google search for "how do I implement a Java hashCode method".

Hint: String already implements a hashCode method.